# How to change PHP code style in PhpStorm IDE?

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm

I'm using Laravel framework. I want to change the default code style format from this:

```php
 return [
            'name' => 'required|min:4|string',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
            'password' => 'required|min:4|confirmed',
            'password-confirmation' => 'required|min:4'
        ];
```

**to this:**

```
return [
            'name'                  => 'required|min:4|string',
            'email'                 => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
            'password'              => 'required|min:4|confirmed',
            'password-confirmation' => 'required|min:4'
        ];
```

I did a lot of searches in PhpStorm settings but I couldn't find the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `File | Settings` (`PhpStorm | Preferences` on macOS)
2. `Editor | Code Style | PHP`
3. `Wrapping and Braces` tab
4. `Array initializer | Align key-value pairs` option

[image]